# Why does "block title" affect all, but "block body" only the regular block style?

Tags: beamer, themes

I am still in the development of a theme for beamer and I found something that I can't understand. Usually in beamer there is a template and sometimes there is a parent template, from which you can set multiple templates to the same style at once.

Now let's have a look on the blocks, that come in three flavors:

1. Regular blocks
2. Alert blocks
3. Example blocks

But as far as I see in the manual and in the code, these only share the `Parent Beamer-Template blocks` which is defined as:

```
\defbeamertemplateparent{blocks}{block begin,block end,%
  block alerted begin,block alerted end,%
  block example begin,block example end}
{}
```

All other templates, especially title and body are not linked, as far as I can see.

But given this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{An alert block}
    Shall alert people
\end{alertblock}
\begin{exampleblock}{An example block}
    Shall explain something to people
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}{A general block}
    For everything else
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

As you can see in this image, all titles are set to `\scriptsize`, but only the body of the regular `block` changes to `\scriptsize`, the others stay at their natural size.

Why is this? I am asking because I don't see any link here. E.g. the `block alerted begin` is defined as:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{block alerted begin}{default}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title alerted}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title alerted}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title alerted}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body alerted}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body alerted}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body alerted}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body alerted}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
```

So how can it be that the font sizes for alerted and example block titles are changing? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There three environments `block`, `alertblock`, and `exampleblock`

- use font templates `block title`, `block title alerted`, and `block title example` for their titles respectively, in which the latter two both *inherit* from the first one, and
- use font templates `block body`, `block body alerted`, and `block body example` for their bodies, in which there are no inheritance in between them.

```
% beamerfontthemedefault.sty, lines 81-86
\setbeamerfont{block body}{}
\setbeamerfont{block body alerted}{}
\setbeamerfont{block body example}{}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,parent={structure,block body}}
\setbeamerfont{block title alerted}{parent={block title,alerted text}}
\setbeamerfont{block title example}{parent={block title,example text}}
```

([link](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/bce3220887c694ffeb5268f4f033fc2366c55cd2/base/themes/font/beamerfontthemedefault.sty#L81-L86) to related source lines)

Hence

- when you change font template `block title`, it influences titles in each of three environments, while
- when you change font template `block body`, it influences title in `block` environment alone.

The consistent inheritance relation can be achieved by specifying `parent=block body` for those two font templates, see

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{block body alerted}{parent=block body}
\setbeamerfont{block body example}{parent=block body}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{alertblock}{An alert block}
      Shall alert people
  \end{alertblock}
  
  \begin{exampleblock}{An example block}
      Shall explain something to people
  \end{exampleblock}
  
  \begin{block}{A general block}
      For everything else
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Some source file references (with default theme used):

- All three environments are defined in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`.
- `block` environment calls template `block begin`, which is defined in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`
- `alertblock` and `example block` environments call templates `block alerted begin` and `block title example` respectively, which are both defined in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`.
- In each of three templates, one font templates is used when typesetting title, another one for body.
- All six font templates mentioned above are defined in `beamerfontthemedefault.sty`.

---

PS: This might be a design or implementation error of `beamer`.

Comment: I've reported to `beamer`, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/612.